# Polygonize large raster to create mask gives memory error

Tags: python, geopandas, geoprocessing, memory, large-datasets

I have a very large land cover/land use raster for South America with dimensions (y: 162565, x: 188387) at the Landsat 30m resolution. I want to use it to mask another raster for the same area at 270m resolution, with dimensions (lat: 27600, lon: 19600). The idea is to count how many invalid 30m pixels (i.e., urban/crop, pixelvalue=1) fall within the larger 270m pixel, and mask if that sum exceeds a certain threshold. For smaller areas I have successfully implemented this using the following script:

```
import xarray
import numpy as np
import rioxarray
import geopandas
from shapely.geometry import mapping
import rasterio as rio
from shapely.geometry import box
from shapely.geometry import shape

#Import tree cover data to be masked
tc = xarray.open_rasterio("SA_TC.tif").squeeze('band', drop=True)
tc.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="x", y_dim="y", inplace=True)
tc.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)

#Import landcover
lc = xarray.open_rasterio("SA_LC.tif").squeeze('band', drop=True)
lc.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="x", y_dim="y", inplace=True)
lc.rio.write_crs("epsg:4326", inplace=True)

#Transform
trans = list(lc.transform)
trans[2]=lc.x.values.min()
trans[-1]=lc.y.values.max()
input_transform = trans

# Create array with a unique value per cell
def create_vectors(lc):
    unique_pixels = np.arange(lc.size,dtype=np.int16).reshape(lc.shape)
    # Vectorise each unique feature in array
    vectors = rio.features.shapes(
        source=unique_pixels, transform=input_transform
    )
    return vectors

vectors = create_vectors(lc)

# Extract polygons and values from generator
vectors = list(vectors)
polygons = [shape(polygon) for polygon, value in vectors]

# Create a geopandas dataframe populated with the polygon shapes
gdf = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(data={"id": lc.values.flatten()}, geometry=polygons,crs=lc.crs)

#Now create larger, 270m grid
# total area for the grid
xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax= tc.x.values.min(),tc.y.values.min(),tc.x.values.max(),tc.y.values.max()

# cell_sizes
cell_sizex = tc.transform[0]
cell_sizey = tc.transform[-2]

# projection of the grid
crs = tc.crs

# create the cells in a loop
grid_cells = []
for x0 in np.arange(xmin, xmax+cell_sizex, cell_sizex):
    for y0 in np.arange(ymax, ymin+cell_sizey, cell_sizey):
        # bounds
        x1 = x0+cell_sizex
        y1 = y0+cell_sizey
        grid_cells.append( box(x0, y0, x1, y1)  )


cell = geopandas.GeoDataFrame(grid_cells, columns=['geometry'], 
                                 crs=crs)

#Now merge
merged = geopandas.sjoin(gdf, cell, how='left')

# Compute stats per grid cell
dissolve = merged.dissolve(by="index_right", aggfunc="sum")
# put this into cell
cell.loc[dissolve.index, 'id'] = dissolve.id.values
```

As I said, this works fine for smaller areas, but for the full raster it crashes early in the script at the command

```
# Extract polygons and values from generator
vectors = list(vectors)
```

even with large memory allocated (>400Gb), yielding the following error

```
ERROR 1: CPLRealloc(-6442451024): Silly size requested.
ERROR 1: CPLRealloc(-6442451024): Silly size requested.
srun: error: mem002: task 0: Segmentation fault
```

My question is: is there a way to deal with this? Or a better way to perform the masking in a similar fashion (counting how many invalid pixels)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following workflow:

- Create a 0=valid/1=not valid 30m raster,
- resample to 270m with average resampling.
- Pixel values (average of invalid pixels) that are greater than a specified threshold e.g. 25% will form the mask.

```
import xarray
from rasterio.enums import Resampling

src = "SA_LC.tif"
dst= "SA_LC_mask.tif"

invalid = 1  # invalid landcover pixel value
threshold = 0.25   # >25% of 30m pixels in a 270m pixel are invalid

#Import landcover
lc = xarray.open_dataset(src, engine="rasterio").squeeze('band', drop=True)
lc.rio.set_spatial_dims(x_dim="x", y_dim="y", inplace=True)

scale_factor = 9  # 270/30 == 9
new_width = int(lc.rio.width / scale_factor)
new_height = int(lc.rio.height / scale_factor)
lc_mask = ((lc == invalid).astype("float").rio.reproject(
     lc.rio.crs,
     nodata=0,
     shape=(new_height, new_width),
     resampling=Resampling.average,
) > threshold).astype("byte")

lc_mask.rio.to_raster(dst)  # save the mask if you wish or just use the lc_mask Dataset
```

I would also suggest using [Dask](https://corteva.github.io/rioxarray/stable/examples/dask_read_write.html#Example---Reading-and-Writing-with-Dask) (setting `chunks` to a multiple of 9) when reading the massive LC dataset....